How to Debug xv6-riscv in VSCode: Issues with Kernel and User Mode Debugging
I am trying to debug xv6-riscv from VSCode. I have successfully managed to debug the kernel mode, although it required a bit of a workaround. Here's the configuration I am using:
In my tasks.json, I have the following for compiling xv6 in debug mode:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "compile xv6 and run in debug mode",
            "command": "bash",
            "args": ["-c", "make CPUS=1 qemu-gdb"],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": true,
                "panel": "new",
                "showReuseMessage": true,
                "clear": true
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}

And my launch.json is configured like this (I have the "Native Debug" extension installed):
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug xv6-riscv with Native Debug",
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "attach",
            "executable": "${workspaceFolder}/kernel/kernel", 
            "target": "localhost:26000",                   
            "remote": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "gdbpath": "/usr/bin/gdb-multiarch",            
            "autorun": [
                "set architecture riscv:rv64",
                "file kernel/kernel"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "valuesFormatting": "parseText",
            "showDevDebugOutput": true,
            "printCalls": true
        }
    ]
}

Usually, when I run the build task, a .gdbinit file is automatically generated, which looks like this:
set confirm off
set architecture riscv:rv64
target remote 127.0.0.1:26000
symbol-file kernel/kernel
set disassemble-next-line auto
set riscv use-compressed-breakpoints yes

Here, target remote 127.0.0.1:26000 connects gdb to the debug session. The issue is that the same instruction is also present in my launch.json. When gdb attempts to connect again, the session terminates automatically. To make it work, I have to manually remove this line from .gdbinit and then run the launch task to debug in kernel mode successfully.
My issues are:

How do I remove the target from the launch.json file? It seems to be a mandatory field, and without it, the config does not work, but having it causes a double connection attempt.

How can I debug xv6-riscv in user mode? I have tried setting the executable field to ${workspaceFolder}/user/_someProgram, but this does not seem to work. While I can debug kernel mode, I am unsure how to achieve user-mode debugging.


Any help on these two issues would be greatly appreciated!
